# How does cookie fork if it wont show my cookie what i set?

Tags: php, cookies

```
<?php 


if (isset($_POST['pieslegsanas'])){  

  require  '../conn.php';
  global $conn;
  

  $email = $_POST['epasts'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];  
 
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_acounts WHERE e_pasts=?;";
  $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn); // Inicializācija 

 if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
  header ('location: ../login.php?error');
  exit();

  }else{

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $email);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt); // Iegūst rezultātu       
  }

  if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ // Šeit gaidāma tikai viena atbilde  
   
    $password_check = password_verify($password, $row["PAROLE"]);      
      if ($password_check == false){        
        header ('location:   ../login.php?password=false');
        exit();

      }else if ($password_check == true){   
        session_start();            
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row["id"];
        $_SESSION['NAME'] = $row["VARDS"];        
        $_SESSION['SURNAME'] = $row["UZVARDS"];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $row["E_PASTS"]; 
        $_SESSION['status'] = $row['STATUSS'];
        $_SESSION['school'] = $row["SKOLA"];        
        $_SESSION['class'] = $row["KLASE"];          
        setcookie("rememberme", $_SESSION['NAME'] . "," . $key, time() * 3600);
        if ($_SESSION['status'] == 'Nav'){
          header ('location:   ../status.php');
          exit();
        }else{
        header('location:   ../main.php?id='.$_SESSION['user_id'].'');
        exit();
        }
      }
   } else {
     header ('location: ../login.php?email=false');
     exit();
   }
   mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
   mysqli_close($conn);
  
}

 

?>
```

Hey! So I am making a website for persons who want to trie to complete some tests and I want to make a login and with a cookie, so I am trying to set a cookie after person presses a button to login and then I want to make a time delay if he isn't on his pc it will end the session.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to enforce the session both in the backend, as in the frontend. The cookie has a set lifetime, and doesn't know about user interactions.

You'll have to listen for page interactions via JavaScript, if you want an educated guess whether the user is still present and active. Of course, you'll never know if it was their cat walking over the keyboard, or whether the user is afk but still watching the screen (and mentally engaged with the system).

To get you going, some events you might want to look at are `mousedown`, `keyup`, and `touchstart` on the top element (html). Read up on passive event handling if you don't want to risk compromising scroll performance.